# Extract acres from legal description

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

[image]

I need to extract the acres from the legal description.  I have tried 
"(!Legal!.split(" AC")[-1])" but it gave an error. I am using ArcGIS 10.2 using python in the field calculator. I realized why my scrip wouldn't work but can't quite figure it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: what about "(!Legal!.split(" ")[-2])"?

Comment: That would work but Acres isn't always at the end of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
!Legal!.split(" AC")[0].split(" ")[-1]
```

The first split will separate the rest of the text from " AC" and the second will give you last text element separated by a space.

Comment: Some of the descriptions have more than one acreage listed, though, Regex would work well here, but damned if I can ever figure it out.

Comment: I get an error "Whitespace is not allowed at this location".  Also I would always need the last acre listed or total.

Comment: I tested this on text fields.  Are you trying to calculate for a numeric field?

Comment: No.  On a text field.

Comment: @recurvata Is correct, there are multiple occurrences of AC in the text.  Regex would be the way to go.

Comment: Since it looks like if "ac" is in the field more than once, the total acreage will be listed as "3.4 AC TOTAL", so what about doing a conditional test for the word "TOTAL" in the field? If it is take the split()[-3]. If it's not take the split()[-2].

Comment: "COLEMAN TWP; N1/2 SW1/4; SE1/4 SW1/4;30-32-12;120.58 AC "  The previous field was causing the error.  No space before the number.  Put a space in there and it worked just fine. Thanks

Comment: Also the total is always last in the field, so i will do a search for those and fix accordingly by changing the code to: `!Legal!.split(" AC")[1].split(" ")[-1]`